# Multiplicative group of countable fields

Tags: fields

Is there a countable field such that the multiplicative group of that field is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$?

Comment: No. If the field has characteristic 0, then it contains a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$, therefore its multiplicative group contains $\mathbb{Q}^*$. If the field has positive characteristic $p$, then it contains a copy of $\mathbb{F}_p$, therefore it has an invertible element $x$ such that $x^p = 1$.

Comment: Google says no:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753437/why-must-a-field-with-a-cyclic-group-of-units-be-finite

Comment: No. In characteristic $\neq 2$, $-1$ has order 2. In characteristic 2, either $K$ is algebraic over $F_2$ and hence $K^*$ is torsion, or it has a transcendental element $x$. Since $x$ and $x+1$ freely generate a copy of $\mathbf{Z}^2$ in $K^*$, we conclude.

Comment: @July the only $p$-th root of 1 in char $p$ is 1, so your argument does not work. Using the copy of $F_p$ still works, but only for $p\neq 2$.

Comment: @Ycor: oops, you are right of course about $p\neq 2$. Also, I meant $x^{p-1}=1$.

Comment: cont.: and $x\neq 1$.

Comment: Actually this shows that for any field, as an abelian group, the $\mathbf{Q}$-rank of $K^*$ (the maximal cardinal of a $\mathbf{Z}$-free family inside $K^*$) is either 0 or infinite (and is 0 precisely for algebraic extensions of finite fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m going to say no. You want the non-zero elements to be $\cdots,x^{-1},1,x,x^2,\cdots$ where $x^k \neq 1$ for $k \neq 0.$

If the characteristic is a finite number $p$ then $1+x=x^j$ for some $j.$ If $j \gt 1$ this only allows $p^j$ elements. In case $j=-t \lt 0$ we have $x^t+x^{t+1}=1$ and $p^{t+1}$ elements.

In case of infinite characteristic every rational number is $x^j$ for a unique $j.$ In case that is not convincing enough, $2=x^j$ makes the field $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[j]{2}]$ which does not have the desired property, even for $j=\pm1.$